# Possible to comment a pylint annotation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I would like to disable a warning in `pylint` and also say why I'm disabling it:

```
from typing import Union, NoReturn, Optional # pylint: disable=unused-import (unused because hack for forward declaration!)
```

But this gives me the error:

> bad-option-value: Bad option value 'declaration'

Is there a way to comment/provide context on why a warning is disabled? Or does it have to be on another line in order to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for parsing these "pragma" comments is here:

https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/master/pylint/utils/pragma_parser.py

It says:

> Allow stopping after the first semicolon/hash encountered,
> so that an option can be continued with the reasons
> why it is active or disabled.

So **yes**, it is possible.

If I understand this code correctly, you should be able to use

```
# pylint: disable=unused-import # unused because hack for forward declaration!
```

or

```
# pylint: disable=unused-import ; unused because hack for forward declaration!
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the 'correct' answer but from a bit of trial and error, adding another comment char `#` after the annotation/disable allows stops the interpretation of the `pylint`. For example:

```
from typing import NoReturn, Optional # pylint: disable=unused-import # my comment here...
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you put semicolon after `disable=unused-import`?

i.e.

```
from typing import Union, NoReturn, Optional # pylint: disable=unused-import; (unused because hack for forward declaration!)
```

Reference: http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html